# Checking for an empty result (PHP, PDO, and MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What am I doing wrong here? I'm simply retrieving results from a table and then adding them to an array. Everything works as expected until I check for an empty result...

This gets the match, adds it to my array and echoes the result as expected:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now'));

$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id_email FROM db WHERE hardcopy = '1' AND hardcopy_date <= :today AND hardcopy_sent = '0' ORDER BY id_email ASC");

$sth->bindParam(':today', $today, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if(!$sth->execute()) {
    $db = null;
    exit();
}

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $this->id_email[] = $row['id_email'];
    echo $row['id_email'];
}

$db = null;
return true;
```

When I try to check for an empty result, my code returns 'empty', but no longer yields the matching result:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now'));

$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id_email FROM db WHERE hardcopy = '1' AND hardcopy_date <= :today AND hardcopy_sent = '0' ORDER BY id_email ASC");

$sth->bindParam(':today',$today, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if(!$sth->execute()) {
    $db = null;
    exit();
}

if ($sth->fetchColumn()) {
    echo 'not empty';
    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $this->id_email[] = $row['id_email'];
        echo $row['id_email'];
    }
    $db = null;
    return true;
}
echo 'empty';
$db = null;
return false;
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You're throwing away a result row when you do `$sth->fetchColumn()`. That's not how you check if there are any results. You do

```
if ($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
  ... got results ...
} else {
   echo 'nothing';
}
```

Relevant documentation is here: *[PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)*

Comment: Also if `$sth->fetchColumn()` is true you get as output `not empty` and `empty`.

Comment: Thanks Marc, that makes sense. With respect to rowCount() though, it says it won't work with SELECT on all databases - 'If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.' Are you familiar with another method maybe?

Comment: @Jeffrey - LOL - you're right! I am missing an 'else' in there. Thanks! EDIT - actually, no, it would return correctly, because it

Comment: @canoebrain: you've got 2 choices. fetch all the data and build an array of the results, then count the array. or do a separate `select count(*)`-type query before doing the real "gimme the data" query.

Comment: @Jeffrey - oops, actually, no, I take that back - it would return correctly, because the 'return' exits. If I didn't have the return in there, then yes, I would need an 'else' to make it work.

Comment: @Marc - you're the man! LOL Thanks! Since I need the data if there is any, counting the array of the results is my best bet I think. I'll post exactly what I did as an answer in case it helps someone else, but I'm accepting your answer as correct. Thanks again. Cheers!

Comment: @canoebrain, yeah, haven't even thought it was a function context.

Comment: "You should not use rowCount for SELECT statements..." see below.. It won't work with SQLite for example.

Comment: and your point is? This question is tagged with `mysql`, which does do rowCount properly.

Comment: This may defeat the purpose of using it as a iterator.

Comment: Thankas, that helped.

Comment: `if ($sth->rowCount()) {...}` would be enough because returns 0 for `false` or 1,2,3... for `true`. Advantage of untyped vars in PHP.

Answer (score 14):

If you have the option of using fetchAll() then, if there are no rows returned, it will just be an empty array.

```
count($sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
```

will return the number of rows returned.

Comment: not work in php 8 with no warning. takes me like 5 hours to find this problem

Answer (score 12):

You should not use rowCount for SELECT statements as it is not portable. I use the [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) function to test if a select statement worked:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now'));

$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id_email FROM db WHERE hardcopy = '1' AND hardcopy_date <= :today AND hardcopy_sent = '0' ORDER BY id_email ASC");

// I would usually put this all in a try/catch block, but I kept it the same for continuity
if(!$sth->execute(array(':today'=>$today)))
{
    $db = null;
    exit();
}

$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)

if(!isset($result->id_email))
{
    echo "empty";
}
else
{
    echo "not empty, value is $result->id_email";
}

$db = null;
```

Of course this is only for a single result, as you might have when looping over a dataset.

<sub>I thought I would weigh in as I had to deal with this lately.</sub>

Comment: what if the field in the record is null and other fields have values?

Answer (score 8):

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * from member WHERE member_email = '$username' AND member_password = '$password'");

$sql->execute();

$fetch = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// if not empty result
if (is_array($fetch))  {
    $_SESSION["userMember"] = $fetch["username"];
    $_SESSION["password"] = $fetch["password"];
    echo 'yes this member is registered'; 
}else {
    echo 'empty result!';
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29066770/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: No one should be using this poorly implemented prepared statement.  It makes no sense to call `prepare()` without binding parameters to placeholders in the SQL.  Also, no one should ever be checking a password with a raw string -- all passwords in a database should be hashed (never raw).

Answer (score 3):

> what I'm doing wrong here?

Almost everything.

```
$today = date('Y-m-d'); // no need for strtotime

$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id_email FROM db WHERE hardcopy = '1' AND hardcopy_date <= :today AND hardcopy_sent = '0' ORDER BY id_email ASC");

$sth->bindParam(':today',$today); // no need for PDO::PARAM_STR

$sth->execute(); // no need for if
$this->id_email = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN); // no need for while

return count($this->id_email); // no need for the everything else
```

Effectively, you **always** have your fetched data (in this case in `$this->id_email` variable) to tell whether your query returned anything or not. Read more in [my article on PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count).

Answer (score 1):

One more approach to consider:

When I build an HTML table or other database-dependent content (usually via an AJAX call), I like to check if the SELECT query returned any data before working on any markup.  If there is no data, I simply return "No data found..." or something to that effect.  If there is data, then go forward, build the headers and loop through the content, etc.  Even though I will likely limit my database to MySQL, I prefer to write portable code, so rowCount() is out.  Instead, check the the column count. A query that returns no rows also returns no columns.

```
$stmt->execute();
$cols = $stmt->columnCount(); // no columns == no result set
if ($cols > 0) {
    // non-repetitive markup code here
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

Comment: This will not work as expected.  From the documentation for columnCount(): the number of columns in the result set represented by the PDOStatement object, EVEN IF THE RESULT SET IS EMPTY. If there is no result set, PDOStatement::columnCount returns 0.
(emphasis mine).  This means the while loop will always run and since you do not check for ===false in your while loop, you would have a problem.  Tried this out myself and while the query returned no results, column count was 11, the number of columns that would have been there had there been any results.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Marc B's help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478206/checking-for-empty-result-php-pdo-and-mysql/13478250#13478250), here's what worked for me (note: Marc's rowCount() suggestion could work too, but I wasn't comfortable with the possibility of it not working on a different database or if something changed in mine... also, his select count(*) suggestion would work too, but, I figured because I'd end up getting the data if it existed anyway, so I went this way).

```
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now'));

$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT id_email FROM db WHERE hardcopy = '1' AND hardcopy_date <= :today AND hardcopy_sent = '0' ORDER BY id_email ASC");

$sth->bindParam(':today', $today, PDO::PARAM_STR);

if(!$sth->execute()) {
    $db = null;
    exit();
}

while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $this->id_email[] = $row['id_email'];
    echo $row['id_email'];
}
$db = null;

if (count($this->id_email) > 0) {
    echo 'not empty';
    return true;
}
echo 'empty';
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I only found one way that worked...

```
$quote = $pdomodel->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM MyTable");

//if (!is_array($quote)) {  didn't work
//if (!isset($quote)) {  didn't work

if (count($quote) == 0) {   //yep the count worked.
    echo 'Record does not exist.';
    die;
}
```

Comment: oh i found another way that worked too.  

     if ($quote == null) { echo 'No record exists'; }

Comment: if the query does not return any row then this "if (count($quote) == 0)" does not work but this "if ($quote == null)" works fine in both case. Thank you @hamish