# PHP With Row Number And If Else

Tags: php, html

I am running a sql query and getting a count of the results using PHP.  The below is the relevant parts of my syntax and what I want to do is if the count returned is >= 1 then display the grid (as it will be populated with 1 or more rows), but if the row count returned is 0 then display a warning on screen notifying the user.

My issue with the code is that it always returns the grid!

```
<?php

//Connection to server to run sql query and return results

$numofrows = mssql_num_rows($tsql);

?>

if ($numofrows >= 1) {
    //Build out HTML Table
} else {
    //write on screen there are no results to display
}
```

**EDIT**
This is how I am setting it up which appears to be the same as the link in the comments

```
<?php

//Connection to server to run sql query and return results

$numofrows = mssql_num_rows($tsql);

?>

if ($numofrows >= 1) {
    <table border="1">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th >Header 1 </th>
    <th>Header 2 </th>
    <th>Header 3 </th>
    <th>Header 4 </th>
    <th>Header 5</th>
    <th>Header 6 </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    foreach( $query as $res ) { 
    print "<tr>";
    print "<td>" .$res->Field1."</td>";
    print "<td>" .$res->Field2."</td>";
    print "<td>" .$res->Field3."</td>";
    print "<td>" .$res->Field4."</td>";
    print "<td>" .$res->Field5."</td>";
    print "<td>" .$res->Field6."</td>";
    print "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
} else {
    echo "<strong>No Results</strong>"
}
```

Comment: why are you closing the `?>` before `if-else` ?

Comment: I was using HTML to write out the table - can the html be perfomed inside the php code tag?

Comment: yes! use `echo`

Comment: Or put `?>` inside the loop in the `if` block.

Comment: @IU5er - I just looked at my code, and for some reason I have the data from sql being written to the table in php code tags and am using the print statement.  Is that effectively the same as an echo statement, print that is?

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh, try out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21809991/creating-a-dynamic-table-using-php-based-on-users-input-data. Use the given way to make the table within your `if` block and in the `else` section, just `echo "Nothing to display"`

Comment: @IU5er - see my edit.  That is my syntax, which appears to be the same as the SO link you provided...

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh, no! you missed the `<?php` in the example

Comment: @BellHopByDayAmetuerCoderByNigh Well here, you do this, and let me know. Give `<?php` at the very beginning and `?>` at the very end and don't use either of them in the middle

Comment: @IU5er - I must be missing it then.  From what I see the php is not encompassing the table header info, but it is when you write the data to the table.  To me that is how my syntax is set-up .

Comment: @IU5er -> ah I did not realize I could wrap the entire blcok in a php tag.  I thought the table header info had to be outside of that.

Comment: Mysql is deprecated, use mysqli instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approximate example, to help you out.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Select Database
mysqli_select_db($conn, "test");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#06160F">
            <table frame="hsides" style="color:#ffffff;">
               <!-- Headers of the table -->
                <tr>
                        <th>Header 1 </th>
                        <th>Header 2 </th>
                        <th>Header 3 </th>
                        <th>Header 4 </th>
                        <th>Header 5</th>
                        <th>Header 6 </th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <table border="1" width="960px">
                    <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM abc";

                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                    if($result)
                    {
                        if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
                        {echo"<table>";
                         // output data of each row
                         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
                         {
                             echo"<tr>";
                             echo"<td width=120px align=\"center\">".$row["feild1"]."</td>";
                             echo"<td width=170px align=\"center\">".$row["feild2"]."</td>";
                             echo"<td width=120px align=\"center\">".$row[""feild3"]."</td>";
                             echo"<td width=170px align=\"center\">".$row["feild4"]."</td>";
                             echo"<td width=420px align=\"center\">".$row["feild5"]."</td>";
                             echo"<td width=420px align=\"center\">".$row["feild6"]."</td>";
                             echo"</tr>";
                         }
                         echo"</table>";
                        }
                        else 
                            echo "<h3 align=\"center\">Nothing to show.</h3>";
                    }
                    else
                        echo "<br> Database error.";
                    $conn->close();     
                    ?>
                </table>
            </div>
            <br>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

By the way I'm using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check this answer: [Checking for empty result (php, pdo, mysql)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13478206/checking-for-empty-result-php-pdo-mysql)

I think also, you should use PDO.

Comment: I have never been able to geta  succesful connection using PDO.  I am running this syntax inside an article on my Joomla article. -- using the Sourcerer extension

Comment: What's your problem with PDO? I learned to use PDO with this example http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/php/select-statements-with-pdo/ and had never any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Your if loop is outside the php section, so it won't be evaluated