# It doesn't stop going to else part, issue with if statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement, rowcount

i typed the login and password 100000 times but it dont stop going to ELSE part. where's the error?

```
if (!empty($user) AND !empty($password)) {
    $sql = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = :user AND password = :password");
    $sql->execute(array('user' => $user, 'password' => $password));

    if ($sql->rowCount()) {
        $data = $sql->fetch();
        $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = true;
        header('location:client.php');
    } else {
        echo "user or password are wrong";
    }
}
```

[image: here is the output, when it should enter another web page]

Comment: Passwords should be hashed with [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). If it is hashed, it will never match what is in the database. Instead, you need to select the user, and if it exists, then use [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to match it.

Comment: PDOStatement::rowCount() returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object. It's not useful for `SELECT` statements.

Comment: ...and to finish GrumpyCrouton's point, you're not running any of those, you're running a SELECT. So rowCount isn't the appropriate function to use here. https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php . (As it says, _some_ databases might return the number of rows the SELECT generated, but you can't rely on it). This: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29066770/5947043 should help you

Comment: If that doesn't help you (maybe because rowCount is actually returning a valid value), then the only other explanation is that the query returned no rows (perhaps because the data you entered didn't match any of them, or because none exist at all).

Answer (score 2):

PDOStatement::fetch() would return false if your query returns 0 row(s).

```
if (!empty($user) AND !empty($password)) {
    $sql = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = :user AND password = :password");
    $sql->execute(array('user' => $user, 'password' => $password));

    if ($data = $sql->fetch()) {
        $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
        // Why overwrite session id with true?
        // $_SESSION['id'] = true;
        header('location:client.php');
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "user or password are wrong";
    }
}else {
    echo "user or password are wrong";
}
```

Comment: it goes to else part saying 'user or pass are wrong'

Comment: This is basically the same as my existing answer.

Comment: @kebyzak Your query must have returned 0 rows.

Answer (score 1):

[`PDOStatement::rowCount()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object. It's not useful for `SELECT` statements.

Instead, get the results using `fetch()` (Which is used to return a single row) and just check if it's empty.

```
$sql = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = :user AND password = :password");
$sql->execute(array('user' => $user, 'password' => $password));

$data = $sql->fetch();

if(!empty($data)) {
    $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
    header('location:client.php');
    die();
}
//this line will only execute if the query returns nothing
echo "user or password are wrong";
```

NOTE: The `die()` function will make PHP stop executing code, but the `header()` is already set so it will still redirect. This means if login is successful, it will not execute anything after the IF statement.

---

### More Security

**WARNING**: Passwords should be hashed with [`password_hash()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). If it is hashed, it will never match what is in the database. Instead, you need to select the just the user, and if it exists then you use [`password_verify()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to verify the password.

If you have passwords stored properly, your query will look like this:

```
$sql = $this->_db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user = :user");
```

and your IF statement will look like this:

```
if(!empty($data)) {
    //user exists
    if(password_verify($password, $data['password'])) {
        //password verified
        $_SESSION['id'] = $data['id'];
        header('location:client.php');
        die();
    }
}
//this line will only execute if the username doesn't exist or the password is incorrect
echo "user or password are wrong";
```